# Action Script. Remove all objects with Try Again button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, parent-child, removechild

I'm creating Flash "memory" game, Idea to discover 2 equal cards. And I need to make "Try again" button, which remove all cards and spawn new.

Here is main game function:

```
public function MemoryGame()
{
    tryAgain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, darKarta);
        timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick

        txtTime = new TextField();
        addChild(txtTime);
        tmpTime = timer.currentCount;
        timer.start();

    _cards = new Array();
    _totalMatches = 18;
    _currentMatches = 0;
    createCards();
}
```

Here is createCards function:

```
private function createCards():void
        {
            _cardX = 45;
            _cardY = 10;

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _boarder = new Boarder();
                _card.setType(_boarder);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 5;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }

            for(var j:Number = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _blueBoard = new BlueBoard();
                _card.setType(_blueBoard);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 5;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }
                        for(var r:Number = 0; r < 2; r++)
            {
                _card = new Card();
                addChild(_card);
                _penktas = new Penktas();
                _card.setType(_penktas);
                _card.x = _cardX;
                _card.y = _cardY;
                _cardX += _card.width + 5;
                _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
                _cards.push(_card);
            }
```

And here is removeCard function:

```
function removeCards(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //for(var iv:Number = 0; iv < 18; iv++)
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, remCards);
    //}
}

function remCards(evt:Event):void
{
   if (contains(_card)) {
    removeChild(evt.currentTarget._card);
   }
}
```

But It removes only last card, I don't know how to make to delete them all. Have you any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to add all the cards inside a container `MovieClip` and not directly to the stage.

```
CardContainer.addChild(_card);
```

and when you want to remove all the cards then either remove the CardContainer MovieClip and re add it to the stage. or you can do this in your `removeCards` function to remove all cards from it like :

```
function removeCards(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   while(CardContainer.numChildren > 0)
   {
       CardContainer.removeChildAt(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I got error: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` What's wrong? I used private `var CardContainer:Card;` is It good?

Comment: Take CardContainer as a MovieClip and declare it above the main `MemoryGame` constructor so that all functions within that class can access it and add to the stage inside the `MemoryGame()` Constructor:

`private var CardContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

public function MemoryGame()
{

    addChild(CardContainer);`

//rest of the code here

}`

Comment: Thank you, now It works without errors, but the same as first, deleting only 1 card

Comment: Maybe here is possibility to delete objects by type? As you see I add 1_card.setType(_blueBoard); // _card.setType(_penktas);` If here is any possibility to delete like `removeChild(_card._type:_blueBoard);`? This doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you added all the Cards inside `CardContainer`, make sure you have used the `CardContainer.addChild(_card);` in all 3 of your `for` loops?