# Action Script 3. How to hide button till game ends?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript, hide

I'm creating game and I need to make that when game over "Try Again" button appears. I have done the button just don't know how to hide It till game ends. It is shown all the time.

This is my button:

```
function tryAgain(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Try again");
    createCards();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.visible = false;
function tryAgain(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    button.visible = true;
    createCards();
}
```

[`visible` property on AS3 Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#visible)

Comment: Need to wait 4 more minutes, I will do It. Thank you again.

Comment: Maybe do you know something about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386572/action-script-remove-all-objects-with-try-again-button

Answer (score 0):

Use "visibility" property to hide DisplayObject's (Button or SimpleButton are DisplayObject's).

```
button.visible = false;
```